# radium not installing found 3337 high severity vulnerabilities

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, radium

I'm trying to install radium in react for inline pseudo classes or elements to add in my application but it is showing 3337 high severity vulnerabilities?
what the solution of that, i can use classes and ids for styling but i want to use inline styling because everything in react is JavaScript.

i just tried npm intall --save radium but it is showing error.

npm install --save radium

i just want it to be installed and save along with json so that i can use the version controls and can share it later with someone if i want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `npm audit fix`.

This will try to fix the vulnerabilities that can be automatically fixed. in your packages.

If some where not able to be fixed, required manual review, it's all up to there creators.

Such like:

If `npm audit fix` can't fix a vuln. in package `name-for-package`, it's then the turn for this package's creator to fix it.

You may go to there repo in Github and ask them for solution.

Comment: I run the audit to fix the problem and it did fix the problem and now showing that i should use uuid module instead of radium and i have now installed the uuid package instead of redium
Thanks for your help and time
it really matters a lot :)

Comment: I appreciate this! I am glad it worked for you.
Please make sure to accept the answer, this way, others who are willing to help will know that your problem was solved and, others who have the same problem would know that this answer was the solution of it.
Thanks for your kindness Muhammed.